# Mean Value theorem related

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Assume that $1 \le f(x) \le 2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $x \le f(x) \le 2x$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE. I believe there's a typo in your question. If $f\left(0\right) = 0$, then it's not true that $1 \leq f\left(x\right)$.

Comment: Possibly they mean $1 \le f'(x) \le 2$ rather than $1 \le f(x) \le 2$?

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that you meant to write $1 \le f'(x) \le 2$ rather than $1 \le f(x) \le 2$, you can prove it as follows. First, fix an arbitrary non-zero $x \in \Bbb{R}$ (the result is obvious if $x=0$) and consider the secant line between $0$ and $x$. This has slope $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$. Thus, by MVT, there is some $c \in (0, x)$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{x} = f'(c)$.  But then, because $1 \le f'(c) \le 2$, we must have $1 \le \frac{f(x)}{x} \le 2$. Multiplying by $x$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean $1\leq f'(x) \leq 2$, otherwise, as stated by John Omielan, it is not possible for $f(0)$ to be $0$.

Since $f$ is differentiable on any interval, it is also differentiable on $(0, x)$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we know that there exists a $c \in (0,x)$ such that $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$.

Since $1\leq f'(c) \leq 2$, we have $1\leq \dfrac{f(x)}{x} \leq 2$. Multiply both sides by $x$ to get $x \leq f(x) \leq 2x$.